# button in a nested table that has dynamic id

Tags: watir-webdriver

I am trying to click on a button in a table cell that has a dynamic name with a prefix of button_keep

this is the unique path that firebug has pointed out for the table cell.

```
#mergePatientsSelectedTable > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)
```

I'm trying to get there using the following but it does not find the button.

```
b.table(:id => "mergePatientsSelectedTable").tbody{2}.tr{1}.td{2}.table{1}.tbody{1}.tr{1}.td{1}.button(:index => 0).button(:name => /button_keep/).click
```

I have tried to flash on the cells and use IRB yet it continues to give me an assert that cannot find the button.

Any suggestions . thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to write out the whole path. Each method/locator looks in all descendents, not just direct children. Using entire paths can make the code quite brittle.

So why not just locate the button based on the known attributes:

```
b.table(:id => "mergePatientsSelectedTable").button(:name => /button_keep/).click
```

But to explain why you were having problems with your solution, doing `tbody{2}` actually returns the first tbody element (not the second). The `{2}` is a block that gets ignored.

For example, consider the html:

```
<div>hi</div>
<div>bye</div>
```

You can see the first div gets returned when using a block:

```
b.div{2}.text
#=> "hi"
```

To get the second div, you can either use the index locator or get the second element of the collection:

```
b.div(:index => 1).text
#=> "bye"

b.divs[1].text
#=> "bye"
```

So if you really wanted to do the entire path, you could have done:

```
b.table(:id => "mergePatientsSelectedTable").tbody(:index => 1).tr.td(:index => 1).table.tbody.tr.td.button(:name => /button_keep/).click
```

Note that:

- `nth-child` is 1-based index while Watir uses a 0-based index.
- If you want the first match, you do not need to include the index - `:index => 0` is assumed.

Comment: justin, thanks this helped me. I did not understand that tr and td could not be provided without the [#] ordinal locator.